# How can I parallelize the following snippet of code in python?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I have a bunch of matrix multiplication operations that are performed only row-wise. I was wondering how to speed-up the computation by parallelization:

```
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, (100000, 800))
indices_1 = np.equal(data, 1)
A = np.zeros((100000, 100))
B = np.random.randn(800, 100)

for i in range(100000):
   ones = indices_1[i]
   not_ones = ~indices_1[i]
   B_ones = B[ones]
   B_not_ones = B[not_ones]
   A[i] = (data[i][not_ones] @ B_not_ones) @ np.linalg.inv(B_not_ones.T @ B_not_ones)  
   data[i][ones] = A[i] @ B_ones.T
```

I tried multiprocessor but for some reason, but it did not perform better than sequential. Here is my multiprocessor implementation:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool
pool = ThreadPool() # can also use Pool

def f(i):
   ones = indices_1[i]
   not_ones = ~indices_1[i]
   B_ones = B[ones]
   B_not_ones = B[not_ones]
   A[i] = (data[i][not_ones] @ B_not_ones) @ np.linalg.inv(B_not_ones.T @ B_not_ones)  
   data[i][ones] = A[i] @ B_ones.T


pool.map(f, range(100000))
```

Both yielded the same amount of running time (around 32 seconds). Other parallelization method like `concurrent.futures` did not improve the runtime (used like below):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     result = executor.map(f, range(100000))
```

I also tried to apply `dask` but could not make their framework work in my case. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Multiprocessing has to *copy* your data between processes. It is not suitable for processing a single large chunk of data.

Comment: is GPU an option for you? tried your code with GPU version on Google colab?

Comment: I would remove the for loop entirely and just let numpy handle the matrix operations.

Comment: @ZeelBharatkumarPatel1931006 I just tried with GPU on Google colab, runtime for both has gone down to 28 but the multiprocessor did not improve the runtime.

Comment: you must use multithreading module, because in multiprocessing each process worker gets its own memory and you won't get the result you want, you can use cocurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @joostblack, it would be great to convert to matrix operations, but there are dependencies for each row (I did not include additional operations for simplicity but added them now) which makes it hard for me to come-up with an equivalent matrix operation.

Comment: @mirhossein thanks for suggesting concurrent.futures, but it seems to increase the runtime? I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly, I have used the followed snippet (also updated in the question): "with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     result = executor.map(f, range(100000))"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is it possible to make a shared copy of the matrices? I have seen some examples of it but not sure how to use them exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


data = list(np.random.randint(1, 100, (100000, 800)))
indices_1 = np.equal(data, 1)
A = list(np.zeros((100000, 100)))
B = np.random.randn(800, 100)


def f(data, A, i):
    ones = indices_1[i]
    not_ones = ~indices_1[i]
    B_ones = B[ones]
    B_not_ones = B[not_ones]
    A[i] = (data[i][not_ones] @ B_not_ones) @ np.linalg.inv(B_not_ones.T @ B_not_ones)
    data[i][ones] = A[i] @ B_ones.T

with mp.Manager() as manager:
    data_global = manager.list(data)
    A_global = manager.list(A)

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        results = [ p.apply_async(f, (data_global, A_global, i,)) for i in range(100000) ]
        for i in results:
            i.wait()

    data_global = list(data_global)
    A_global = list(A_global)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, but still no luck :( 
I tried to change the max_workers from 2 to cpu_count()*4, but all of them have higher running time than the sequential counterpart.

Comment: OK, Let me run your code locally, whats the `@` symbol in the code?

Comment: It is equivalent to np.matmul() (I've read it in the NumPy documentation)

Comment: Multithreading in Python is restricted via the Gil. While it can provide performance improvements, it is not immediately equivalent to n times parallel execution.

Comment: I updated the code, I got about 6-7x improvement in speed with 4 cores CPU, Could you verify the output is the same as the sequential

Comment: They are not, A is still all zeros (have not been updated). I just looked this up, and I guess apply_async needs to have a get() call to actually get the results? Not sure though, not an expert in parallel processing in python :(

Comment: I Updated it, Could you try it again?

Comment: I couldnot access the variables outside the manager, so I called them before (like data = mp.Manager().list(data)
A = mp.Manager().list(A)), but it seems only a handful rows were updated. when I ran the iteration for 1000000, I found that usually first 500-600 updates and the rest of it still remain zeros.

Comment: you must access the variables inside `with mp.Manager() as manager` context

Comment: even so, the same result (I've used your latest code). Only the first 500-600 rows are nonzeros

Comment: Right, I updated the code, Could you try it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228658/discussion-between-user3086871-and-mirhossein).